# how to add the route resource in navbar list in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-route

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QvS3.png)Route::resource('/branch','BranchController');

but,

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Route [branch.viewbranch] not defined. (View: /home/praveenkumar/Desktop/makeshbakery/resources/views/layout/sidebar.blade.php) (View: /home/praveenkumar/Desktop/makeshbakery/resources/views/layout/sidebar.blade.php) (View: /home/praveenkumar/Desktop/makeshbakery/resources/views/layout/sidebar.blade.php)[lara[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/110KX.png)

Comment: Please show BranchController.

Comment: branch controller picture added in my question see this and answer to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Router resource will generate to example:

```
(get) index => route('branch.index')
(get) show => route('branch.show', $id)
(get) create => route('branch.create')
(post) store => route('branch.store')
(get) edit => route('branch.edit', $id)
(put/patch) update => route('branch.update')
(delete) destroy => route('branch.delete', $id)
```